# Can I use Thaumaturgy to hide the effect of Detect Magic?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

[*Detect Magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic) makes my character's eyes glow blue. This is a homebrew rule that my group decided on because my *Detect Magic* comes from an Invocation.

This sometimes can be very inconvenient, because it makes it abundantly clear that they have some kind of supernatural sight. Could I use [*Thaumaturgy*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thaumaturgy), which can alter the color of my character's eyes, be used to mask this effect (or at least if it can't stop the glowing, change the eye color to that of my normal color)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### Homebrew Problems require Homebrew Solutions

Under the rules as written by Wizards of the Coast, [*Detect Magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic) does not make a character's eyes glow blue (or any other color). That means you're playing under a homebrew or house rule. You'll need to consult your DM for a homebrew or house rule solution. Nobody else can help you.

Comment: ...I only just remember after reading this that the glowing eyes was a homebew. Oops.

Comment: @PixelArtDragon Well, you have your answer, then. :)

Comment: If this isn't a dupe I wouldn't be surprised if this becomes a dupe target.